# Slick carousel with parallax elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, parallax

I've tried to create a bespoke parallax when the user swipes left/right, using the slick carousel.

Although need to enhance it further so the unseen images reset.

```
$(this).find(".parallaxback img:visible").animate({
   left: increment+"=15"
}, 700, function() {
   // Animation complete.
});
```

Tried to use the : visible selector, but I don't feel its having an effect.

- How would you stabilize this carousel so the elements don't float
  off. Reset the unseen items so they can keep on track?
- Also - is there a way to move the items during a slide?

  http://jsfiddle.net/ayve1nmf/25/

Comment: maybe your approach should be different. Try setting the parallex offset relative to your "scrolling position"

Comment: What do you mean Max? you mean reverse the movement?

Comment: How could you configure it - so the parallax occurs during movement. A mousemove would only handle a drag etc..

Comment: Here is an example - with the reverse.. the items move left, the pictures more right... the items move right, the pictures move left. -- how do you get this going during a drag? http://jsfiddle.net/ayve1nmf/27/

Answer (score 1):

this an example with parallax animating in reverse to the movement. 
Although I'm not sure how you would set the parallax during a drag/during the swipe movement -- instead of after/before its finished the swipe.

http://jsfiddle.net/ayve1nmf/27/

```
var parallaxAnimate = function(el, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    console.log("parallax animate");

    var increment = "+";

     if (currentSlide > nextSlide) {
         increment = "-";
     }

     $(el).find(".parallaxback img:visible").animate({
         left: increment + "=15"
     }, 400, function () {
         // Animation complete.
     });       
};


 // On before slide change
 $('.data').on('beforeChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    console.log("beforeChange");
     //console.log(nextSlide);
     parallaxAnimate(this, currentSlide, nextSlide);
 });
```

Comment: how do you invoke the animation only during movement?